# jQuery blur to check webservice for match and return data to set multiple textboxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

I have a text box that I am the user enters a Supplier Name into.  On the blur I want to check a webservice to see if the Supplier exists, and if it does I would like to return the Supplier ID from the webservice and use it to populate another text box.

The webservice is working fine because I am using it fine in other places (with similar code to do autocomplete) It returns the data in JSON and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<ArrayOfSuppliers xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
  -<Suppliers> 
       <SupplierID>1</SupplierID> 
       <SupplierName>Supplier 1</SupplierName> 
   </Suppliers> 
 </ArrayOfSuppliers>
```

This following code is a mess, and will not work as it is.  I hope that it helps explain what I am trying to do, and also so you can help me to understand what I am doing wrong and how the data is returned and usable.

As a starting point I am getting an error that 'response' is undefined.  I can see why, but I don't understand enough to know what I need to do to fix it.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id$=txtSupplier]").blur(function () {

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "http://localhost:52350/FabRouting/Webservice/SupplierList.asmx/GetSuppliers",
             data: "{ 'SupplierSearch': '" + $("[id$=txtSupplier]").val() + "' }",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
             success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                   return {
                   value: item.SupplierName,
                   id: item.SupplierID
                 }
                 }))
                 },
             error: function(e){
                 $("[id$=lblSupplier]").html("Unavailable");              
             }
         });
        }
        );
    });
```

After I get this working I still need to know how to take what is returned and set a text box, but I can probably work my way through that if I can get this code to somewhat function.

**Edit**

I have some autocomplete working with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".cRejectedOnSDRR").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:52350/FabRouting/Webservice/ReportList.asmx/GetReports",
            data: "{ 'ReportNumberSearch': '" + request.term + "' }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.ReportNumber,
                        id: item.SDRRID
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("[id$=lblRejectedOnSDRRID]").html(ui.item.id);
    },
});
```

});

And was trying to use that as a basis to do what I mentioned at the top with the blur.  I don't understand enough how to simply get and use the data returned from a webservice so I was trying to reverse engineer the autocomplete code to help myself understand it.

Comment: The returned data is `XML`, not `JSON`.

Comment: OK, thanks, my mistake.  While that may cause some problems it is not where my problems start.  I have some poorly written jQuery that I would like to make some heads or tails of and once I get moving on that I can work with the webservice if need be.  This webservice is working fine with other jQuery code that is very similar to this and was my starting point to writing this code.  Any thoughts on my jQuery?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally figured it out.  I was pretty sure I was on the wrong path but I didn't know what I was doing wrong or how to access the data returned from the web service.  Darin was helpful it getting me to fight some more with the code and not give up.  I don't think he fully understood what I wanted to do, but did understand that I was trying to use code that I didn't understand :)  I did use his stringify suggestion in my final result, but it was working without it as well... he was just mentioning this as a better option than the code I was using for that purpose I am assuming.

I finally started to figure out the correct syntax - aka: data.d.SupplierID but even though that seemed to be working for other people on the web it would still not return what I was looking for.  I finally came across someone that was using the index - aka: data.d[0].SupplierID and it finally started to work for me.  I was wondering about the index for a while but didn't understand how to handle it.

Here is the final working code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id$=txtSupplier]").blur(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:52350/FabRouting/Webservice/SupplierList.asmx/CheckSupplier",
            data: JSON.stringify({ SupplierSearch: $("[id$=txtSupplier]").val() }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                if (data.d.length == 0) {
                    $("[id$=lblSupplierID]").html("0");
                }
                else {
                    $("[id$=lblSupplierID]").html(data.d[0].SupplierID);
                }
            },
             error: function(e){
                 $("[id$=lblSupplierID]").html("0");
             }
         });
        }
        );
    });
```

I added the if statement to check for nulls because it was not causing an error when no results were found so I couldn't handle it in the error function.  I am assuming this is by design because a SQL query returning null is not necessarily an error, just something I need to deal with.  If anyone has a better (or correct) way to handle this please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

For starters you need to activate JSON on your web service by decorating it with the `[ScriptService]` attribute because right now it returns XML, not JSON:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class SupplierList: System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public Suppliers[] GetSuppliers(string supplierSearch)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you should use the `JSON.stringify` method instead instead of the string concatenation you did when building your `data` parameter on the client which will ensure proper JSON encoding of the request parameter:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ supplierSearch: $("[id$=txtSupplier]").val() },
```

then inside your `success` callback you are using `data.d` which is fine with JSON enabled web services as they use the `.d` property, but then you seem to be calling some `response` javascript function inside your `$.map` which obviously doesn't exist in your context as you are inside the context of an AJAX request success callback. I guess that's some very poor copy-paste-without-understanding-of-what-the-code-means action on your part from some jQuery UI autocomplete plugin example which uses this function but which has strictly no meaning in your scenario.

So, yeah, the error message that you are receiving right now makes perfect sense. You haven't defined the `response` function and yet you are attempting to invoke it.

If you want to use the jQuery autocomplete plugin, that's not the correct way to use it. You should not subscribe to any blur event. You should read the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) for examples. But I am not even sure what you are trying to achieve.

So here's what you might try if you want to wire this plugin with your web service:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id$=txtSupplier]').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:52350/FabRouting/Webservice/SupplierList.asmx/GetSuppliers',
                data: JSON.stringify({ supplierSearch: request.term },
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.SupplierID,
                            value: item.SupplierName
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

Comment: My web service currently looks like this, and I was under the impression that it returned JSON.  I guess it is pretty obvious that is not :)

    <WebService([Namespace]:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ScriptService> _
Public Class SupplierList
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService


    <WebMethod> _
    Public Function GetSuppliers(SupplierSearch As String) As Generic.List(Of Suppliers)

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how to format code in the comments, but I am using vb.net however it looks like I am doing everything you suggest in the first part of your comment.

Comment: Yeap, seems fine. But inside your success callback you seem to be calling some `response` method. Where does this method come from? I can't see it defined anywhere in your code. Also please use a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug to debug your code. What do you see in the console? Are there some errors? Is the AJAX request being sent? I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, you are correct on all parts. It is some poor copy-paste-without-understanding-of-what-the-code-means action.

I am trying to take some code that I had working for some autocomplete and add some other code to it and tweak it to get it to do what I want it to do.  While I see where that comes from in the old code, you are correct, I don't understand it enough to know what to do with it.  I will show you where I got it from.

Comment: I have updated my answer once again in an attempt to guide you with an example of how you might use the jQuery autocomplete plugin.

Comment: I have the autocomplete working and have just edited my original post to show what I have used to accomplish that.  I was trying to reverse engineer that to help me understand it to use it in the current case of checking a text box on blur and using what was entered to get additional data from the webservice.

Comment: But why are you using the `response` function in this case? It is no longer defined and is the reason why you are getting an error. Why are you trying to reverse engineer it? Isn't the plugin doing what you need? If not, then you will have to write a lot more code than that if you want to reverse engineer the full functionality.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to return more than just true/false from the webservice and I saw that I did that with the autocomplete code so I was just trying to understand and use some of the same ideas to do so with calling the webservice during the blur.  I am clueless, and I know that is obvious, I just am trying to get my head around it and can't seem to - sorry.

Comment: I don't know why I am using the `response` function, I am just using two different pieces of code and trying to make sense of it.  I am working on some of the other things you suggested and trying to get this cleaned up a bit to help make it more understandable what I am trying to do... who knows maybe I can learn a little bit more :)

Comment: By the way, the webservice is getting called, and I can see the post and response in firebug.  I am trying to figure out some of that as well.  Thanks so far

Comment: I guess the part I am having the most trouble understanding is how to use the .d and get access to the different components of this property.  My webservice is being called and returns with data in the response.  I also so the JSON with the elements in d, but I don't understand how to get a handle to those elements.

Comment: Thank you for your help, time, and for your patience.  I ended up getting it to work and posted my findings and resulting code as an answer.  I am sure the code could be written better and if you have any suggestions I would be more than happy to use them.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Like it's done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/511027/66580):

```
var SupplierID = $(data).find("SupplierID").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Majid is right, unless you serialize your XML to JSON this will not work, however I don't think your error is because of this. Have you looked into [GenericHandlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx)?